# dual monitors - Cinnamon panel disappears

Tags: dual-boot, unity, nvidia, multiple-monitors, cinnamon

I use Cinnamon DE for my dual monitor setup. When I maximize **KODI** i.e. full screen mode, in the non-primary monitor the panel (bottom) in my primary monitor disappears. So in order to restore the panel I always have to restart the DE using the command *Alt+F2* with *r*. Is there permanent solution to this issue?
Thank you for your time and attention.
OZooHA

Comment: Sadly there is no solution at this time. There are 2 Bug tickets existing and i know this didn't happen in Linuxmint 17. https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/5460
http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=283521

Comment: Thanks.I noticed that this happens on Arch Linux as well for the same Cinnamon DE.